# Accessing the PC audio input stream

Tags: c#, java, c++, audio, hardware

I would like to be able to access the computers incoming audio input stream which is connected to a radio receiver. I would like to continuously read of the incoming frequencies. I don't really know where to start with this. Any help on the subjuect is highly appreciated. How can I go about accessing the computers hardware in e.g C# or C++? Is there any language which offers APIs for this purpose? I know programming in C, C++, Java and C#, but if there is any other language where it is easier to accomplish then that is preferable.

Comment: What platform, operating system, etc ?

Answer (score 2):

I find the [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) library best for this purpose. It is very cross-platform C++ and allows you to easily get a real time stream in from all manner of audio devices with minimal fuss. The download contains a demo application with an audio demo. You can copy this code to give you a starting point.

The library is free to use in open source software and it has a very modestly priced commercial licence.

Comment: Thanks. I will dvelve into JUCE right away. This might be exactly what I need.

Comment: @yms I fail to understand your downvote.  The license is not indicated as a concern, so your comment and downvote seem irrelevent.  Upvoted to cancel.

Comment: @Andy It was wrong/misleading information. Answers in SO are read by many programmers, not just the original poster of the question. I have changed my vote to +1 though, since the answer was fixed and that was the purpose of my downvote anyway.

Comment: @yms Understood, I didn't see the answer until after the edit.